# make 3 "for" loops wait for async answer. obj-c ios

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an app for iPad iOS 8, and I need to make my app wait for an answer from:

```
[directions calculateETAWithCompletionHandler:^(MKETAResponse *response, NSError *error) {}]
```

This method is inside 3 loops. I tried `dispatch_semaphore_t`, but the app can't continue after this line:

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

and gets stuck. I tried with `dispatch_group_t` and got the same result.
I guess that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I tried to search SO for similar problems and but found nothing. Can someone explain how I could accomplish this?

```
-(void)setTimesMissions {

for (Driver *d in self.dataList) {

    for (Period *p in d.periods) {

            for (Mission *m in p.missions) {

                MKDirections *directions = ....

                    // HERE i want the for loop stop until this completionHandler finish
                    [directions calculateETAWithCompletionHandler:^(MKETAResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                        //and when he finish here continue
                    }];
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider paring down your code sample to only the relevant parts that affect looping and threading. The extra "fluff" in there makes it hard to tell exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: You are doing the wait the wrong way. If you want the app to wait, show an activity indicator in the UI, **don't block threads**. Use the completion handler to perform any action that should be performed when the operation finishes.

Comment: activity indicator  i tried and still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your method in  dispatch_async block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [youClassInstance setTimesMissions];
});
```

And use dispatch_semaphore_wait in your loop

```
- (void)setTimesMissions {
    Mission *home = [[Mission alloc]init];
    Mission *next = [[Mission alloc]init];
    for (Driver *d in self.dataList) {

        home.clientLat = d.centralPointLat;
        home.clientLon = d.centralPointLon;
        home.clientPaddres = d.centralAddress;

        for (Period *p in d.periods) {

            home.times = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            if ([p.periodIx isEqualToString:self.thisPeriodIX]) {

                for (Mission *m in p.missions) {

                    Mission *source = home;
                    Mission *destination = m ;
                    MKPlacemark *placemarkSource = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([source.clientLat doubleValue], [source.clientLon doubleValue]) addressDictionary:nil] ;
                    MKMapItem *mapItemSource = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkSource];

                    MKPlacemark *placemarkDestination = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([destination.clientLat doubleValue], [destination.clientLon doubleValue])addressDictionary:nil] ;
                    MKMapItem *mapItemDestination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkDestination];

                    MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
                    [directionsRequest setSource:mapItemSource];
                    [directionsRequest setDestination:mapItemDestination];
                    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
                    [directionsRequest setRequestsAlternateRoutes:NO];
                    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];

                    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
                    __block double timeTo;

                    [directions calculateETAWithCompletionHandler:^(MKETAResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                        if ( response.expectedTravelTime) {
                            timeTo = response.expectedTravelTime;
                            double ans = timeTo;
                            Time *t = [[Time alloc]init];
                            t.ix = m.serviceIX;
                            t.time = ans;
                            [home.times addObject:t];
                        }

                        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                    }];

                    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
                }

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      // code that should be executed on main queue 
                 });


                if (next.clientPaddres) {
                    home = next;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```